# socket io and lite server issue

Tags: angular, sockets, socket.io, lite-server

i integrated lite-server to my project. One of my page implement socket.io. If any action made of of my browser means same action apply into another browser. For Example, If i scroll or enter some data in to my form means, same data entered into another browser.Please help me.

app module

```
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ng-socket-io';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3000', options: {} };
```

My component

```
import { SocketService } from '../../service/socket.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard-component',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  providers: [ SocketService ]
})
```

lite server command with pm2

```
pm2 start lite-server
```